# How to access the vector inside a vector C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
class CSVReader
{
    string fileName;
    string delimeter;

public:
    CSVReader(string filename, string delm = ",") :
            fileName(filename), delimeter(delm)
    { }

    vector<vector<string> > getData();
};

vector<vector<string> > CSVReader::getData()
{
    ifstream file(fileName);

    vector<vector<string> > dataList;

    string line = "";
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        vector<string> vec;
        boost::algorithm::split(vec, line, boost::is_any_of(delimeter));
        dataList.push_back(vec);
    }
    file.close();

    return dataList;
}
int main()
{
    CSVReader reader("ncov_confirmed.csv");

    vector<vector<string> > dataList = reader.getData();

    for(vector<string> vec : dataList)
    {
        for(string data : vec)
        {
            cout<<data << " , ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

```
                                    |     |
                                    v     v
How can I access the data of this vector<vector<string> > datalist
```

I am pretty new to C++ and I found this on the Internet. I wanted to make so modifications to the code but I don't understand the code. Can anyone tell me what I asked above? Thanks for any help ! And also if you can explain the code, I would be more than happy :)

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What don't you understand about the code?

Comment: Step through this code with your favorite debugger and inspect the variables. You'll see what happens.

Comment: the trick is to realize that you only need to know how to access an element in a vector. That is all you need to access an element in a vector in a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index into the vectors like indexing into a 2D array using the overloaded [] operator.

For example,

```
cout << dataList[0][0] << endl;

dataList[0] gets the first vector<string> in dataList.
```

`Then dataList[0][0] gets the first string in the first vector<string>`

Comment: You may want to check the size to avoid a crash. So dataList.size() for one dimension and dataList[0].size() for the next (if not square you'll have to test every one).

Answer (score 1):

I think the code was completely.

The program will start from **main function**. I have explained some basically ideas in main function. So you can refer it for more understand.

```
int main()
{
    CSVReader reader("ncov_confirmed.csv"); 
    // reader is an object of class CSVReader which was defined from the first of your code.
    // The CSVReader has mission to read values from csv file.
    // it has a child function is getData() to read data from csv file.

    vector<vector<string> > dataList = reader.getData();
    // The reader object after read the data from csv file, data was saved into dataList
    // vector<vector<string> is a 2D container. So this two loops go over each element in the 2D container and print it out.
    for(vector<string> vec : dataList)
    {
        for(string data : vec)
        {
            cout<<data << " , ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion but index order (is the first or second one the row or column of your vector of vectors?) can be confusing at times. Here my recommendation to get it down correctly and mostly elegant:

```
auto &row = dataList[0];
auto val = row[0];
```

Just break down what you mean using a reference. The compiler will optimize it anyways and it is clear what are referring to.

**NOTE:** As some users already told, do a size checking and ensure the data really exist, before you access your vectors of vectors.

Comment: a range-based loop requires no size checking or ensuring that data really exists.

Comment: That's correct :-) but if you want to access individual elements that would not work, unless you use ranges libraries introduced by c++20 ;-)

Comment: i am refering to OPs code where `vec` is an individual element of `dataList`. It is unclear why you suggest to use `[]` and make a note about size checking. Why not `at()` ?